# Show or hide class as a parameter

Tags: javascript

This is basic ,

I can show or hide a class with :

```
 $('.blink').show();
```

but I would like to do the same with a parameter so

```
  var a = "blink";
 $(a).show();
```

will not work obviously and I couldn't find the keywords to look for this in google.

Comment: Best to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+concatenate+javascript) a question first, else some may think there was no research effort

Comment: "Dynamic class jQuery". On a side note, duplicates tend to get downvoted pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append a dot when you use that variable so that the `$` will consider it as a class selector:

```
 var a = "blink";
 $('.'+a).show();
```

Comment: Please don't answer the millionth duplicate of how to X, close in favor of a canonical question instead